# How can I stop date showing as default in MVC3 when not set?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my view I have the following:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndDate)
```

When the code and the model is created I see it sets a default date rather than null for the field that's defined as follows:

```
public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
```

In my view I see the following:

```
{1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}
```

Is there some way that I can make it show/return an empty string if the field is not yet set to a value by my code. Here it just defaults to the above when I create a view and don't set that field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DateTime is a value type which cannot have *no value*.

You have to use nullable of DateTime written like

```
public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
```

Now you can assign the `null` value to your model in the controller:

```
return View(null);
```

Answer (score 4):

Make EndDate [nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx):

```
public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

for a nullable datatime you need to use `DateTime?` type in your model. This way EndDate will have null until it's assigned a value :-)